# Speeding up a method that iterates through text and creates a Map[Tuple2[String, String], Int] Scala

Tags: scala, text-processing

I have a method in a scala program that is creating a Map[Tuple2[String, String], Int] but its running very slow and cant process much text. I can't seem to figure out how to speed it up and make it more efficient. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
def createTuple(words: List[String]): Map[Tuple2[String, String], Int] = {
    var pairCountsImmutable = Map[Tuple2[String, String], Int]()
    val pairCounts = collection.mutable.Map(pairCountsImmutable.toSeq: _*)
    var i = 0
    for (i <- 0 to words.length - 2) {
        val currentCount: Int = pairCounts.getOrElse((words(i), words(i + 1)), 0)
        if (pairCounts.exists(_ == (words(i), words(i + 1)) -> currentCount)) {
            var key = pairCounts(words(i), words(i + 1))
            key = key + 1
            pairCounts((words(i), words(i + 1))) = key
        } else {
            pairCounts += (words(i), words(i + 1)) -> 1
        }
    }
    var pairCountsImmutable2 = collection.immutable.Map(pairCounts.toList: _*)
    return pairCountsImmutable2
}
```

Comment: `var i = 0` is unnecessary, and the first branch of your if can be shortened to `pairCounts(words(i), words(i + 1)) += 1`, but neither of those will significantly improve speed, just readability.

Comment: if reading the text is an io operation you can try using scala futures.

Comment: Might I suggest posting this to codereview.stackexchange.com? They'll be able to give even more help with speed and readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

I have shamelessly borrowed from the answer by TRuhland to give this improved version of my answer that does not fail with empty or single-element lists:

```
def createTuple(words: List[String]): Map[Tuple2[String, String], Int] =
  words
    .zip(words.drop(1))
    .groupBy(identity)
    .mapValues(_.length)
```

#### Original

You appear to be counting adjacent pairs of words is a list of words. If so, something like this should work:

```
def createTuple(words: List[String]): Map[Tuple2[String, String], Int] =
  words
    .sliding(2)
    .map(l => (l(0), l(1)))
    .toList
    .groupBy(identity)
    .mapValues(_.length)
```

This works as follows

1. `sliding(2)` creates a list of adjacent pairs of words
2. `map` turns each pair from a `List` into a tuple
3. `groupBy` groups the tuples with the same value
4. `mapValues` counts the number of pairs with the same value for each pair

This may not be quite what you want, but hopefully it gives an idea of how it might be done.

As a general rule, don't iterate through a list using an index, but try to transform the list into something where you can iterate through the values.

Try to not create `Map`s element-by-element. Use `groupBy` or `toMap`.

Comment: This will throw an exception if `words` has fewer than 2 elements. The OP's code, however, appears to return an empty Map in this case.

Comment: I would assume that creating `Map` with counts by updating it element-by-element is actually faster than `groupBy` (no need to allocate collections for each key).

Comment: @Victor It's more readable and it's still far faster than the OP's code.

Comment: @VictorMoroz updated using groupBy is faster than element-by-element by my (simple) tests

Comment: @TRuhland Did you use mutable or immutable map? I assumed mutable of course.

Comment: @VictorMoroz I tried it both, similar results, but mutable seemed better, more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Your big problem is that `words` is a `List`, and yet you are indexing into it with `words(i)`. That's slow. Change it to be a `Vector` or rework your algorithm to not use indexing.

Also, `pairCounts.exists` is slow, you should use `contains` whenever possible, as it is constant time on a Map.

Answer (score 1):

If we first reduce your code to essence:

```
def createTuple(words: List[String]): Map[(String, String), Int] = {
    val pairCounts = collection.mutable.Map[(String, String), Int]()
    for (i <- 0 until words.length - 1) {
      val pair = (words(i), words(i + 1))
      pairCounts += (pair  -> (pairCounts.getOrElse(pair, 0) + 1))
    }
    pairCounts.toMap
  }
```

To improve speed, don't use indexing on list (as mentioned elsewhere):

```
def createTuple(words: List[String]): Map[(String, String), Int] = {
  val map = collection.mutable.Map[(String, String), Int]()
  words
    .zip(words.tail)
    .foreach{ pair => 
       map += (pair -> (map.getOrElse((pair, 0) + 1)) }
  map.toMap
}
```

Comment: Using a mutable `Map` is likely to be significantly faster than creating a new `Map` each time.